# Surface an XML schema as an ASP.Net user interface in SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, xml, sharepoint, user-interface, xsd

I have a requirement (at the least possible cost, be that custom dev or 3rd party product) to take an XML schema (which is subject to regular change) and surface a UI to this through SharePoint 2010.

The UI cannot require manual changes when the XML schema changes.  So in some way the UI needs to be dynamically generated from the schema file.

Does anyone have any ideas, either 3rd party products that do this or else a development approach which would require the least development effort.

Your thoughts are as always appreciated.